# Spring Data Key Value Derived Delete Support

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-keyvalue

Does Spring Data Key Value support derived delete query methods? It doesn't work for me.

I extended `Repository`, declared a few `CrudRepository` methods, and added these derived query methods to it:

```
List<ChatMessageEntity> findByChatIdOrderBySequenceNumberAsc(String chatId);
List<ChatMessageEntity> removeByChatId(String chatId);
Long deleteByChatId(String chatId);
```

All the unit tests pass except for the 2 derived delete query methods. `removeByChatId` returns the expected list, but does not delete anything. `deleteByChatId` throws this `UnsupportedOperationException`:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Query method not supported.
    at org.springframework.data.keyvalue.repository.query.KeyValuePartTreeQuery.execute(KeyValuePartTreeQuery.java:97)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:462)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:440)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy29.deleteByChatId(Unknown Source)
    at com.pgi.kcondon.axonminexp.service.ChatRepositoryTest.testRemoveByChatId(ChatRepositoryTest.java:159)
```

I'm using Spring Boot 1.3.3.RELEASE, which depends on Spring Data Key Value 1.0.4.RELEASE.

Comment: I've created [DATAKV-135](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAKV-135) to add support for this to the key-value module.

Comment: Thanks @ChristophStrobl. Key Value has been very helpful for building out a new system without having to deal with, or commit to, a specific distributed repository platform.

Comment: Just wanted to add my support for DATAKV-135, it would be very useful to have.